# How do I avoid re-entering administrator password when I try to remove apps with Finder?

Tags: finder, password, permission, administrator, high-sierra

The fact that Finder asks for entering the password each time you try to remove an application makes very hard to cleanup your mac. It seems that it does not even remember the password for one minute.

I am looking for a way to avoid this escalation prompt while still keeping it for some other activities.

I am currently using High-Sierra but I am pretty sure that the solution could apply to Sierra or even Snow-leopard.

Comment: It is a safety thing : making sure you are certain you want to do the operation. For consequences you just have to look at posts such as "Help, I deleted my drive partitions and it won't boot" ...

Comment: Much like using sudo in terminal, password is required.

Comment: I know why, but I asked about to bypass it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that only happens if you try to delete the App from Finder, which is not they best way in my opinion.

If you have downloaded them from the App Store you can go to the Launchpad and click and hold, kind of like deleting apps from iPhone, and apps will start shaking and a cross icon will apear on the top-left of apps that can be deleted that way.

Personally I use AppCleaner as this software also performs a search for other places where the app to delete may have stored data and gives you a preview for you to review and confirm deletion.

I do some development and when I want to emulate first-time installation process/experience I use [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to delete any profile or history data stored outside the App Bundle.

Finally, you can delete apps from Terminal App but I won't provide details as this is not recommended even if you know what you are doing :p.

Comment: No way to install another app to do removal.

Comment: Well you didn't say anything about not been able to install another app. You can use AppleScript or Automator.